# php imap_open transitory IMAP connection broken with localhost dovecot

Tags: php, imap, dovecot

I use the PHP function `imap_open` to connect to a localhost dovecot server. It works most of the time, but sometimes I have *warning*:

> PHP Warning:  imap_open(): Couldn't open stream
> {imap.fluoo.com/imap:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX  Can not
> authenticate to IMAP server: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken
> (authenticate)

When this occur I have in mail *log*:

```
Sep  3 10:38:01 bipbip dovecot: imap(robot.info@XXXXXXX.com)<3325276><ovIENBPLAsV/AAAB>: Connection closed (No commands sent) in=0 out=394 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
```

I haven't this error for distant connexion with Thunderbird or Outlook, only for PHP in localhost.

I have read that the issue is due to SSL but I don't want to disable it.

I use PHP 7.4.22 and dovecot 2.3.7.2.

If you can help me because I want to try to avoid use `@` operator to delete warning...

Comment: The error looks to me like the server timed out the connection because the client didn’t’ send a command.